# graylog2 not showing any data

Tags: graylog2, graylog

I'm new to Graylog2. I'm using it for analyze the stored logs from Elasticsearch.

I have done the setup successfully using this link http://www.richardyau.com/?p=377

But, I parsed the logs to elasticsearch under the index name called "xg-*". Not sure why same has not been replicated in graylog2.

when I check the indices status in graylogs2 web interface, it shows only "graylog2_0" index. Not showing my index.

someone please help me what is the reason behind it.

**Elasticsearch indices details:**

```
[root@xg bin]# curl http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?pretty
green  open graylog2_0    4 0  0 0    576b    576b 
yellow open xg-2015.12.12 5 1 56 0 335.4kb 335.4kb 
[root@xg bin]#
```

**Graylog2 Web indices details:**
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Graylog doesn't support other indexing schemes than its own. If you want to use Graylog to analyze your data, you also have to ingest it through Graylog.

Comment: Thanks for your update. I'm testing user privileges. If I map the test user to "Reader" role, he is unable to access time filter. Means, they are unable to view the Historical data.  Is there any option available to there to enable timefilter for Read-only users ?.

Comment: "Reader" users can access streams (if they've been given the permissions to access those) but not the universal search (covering all messages).

Comment: Ok. Just now noticed, Even for Admin user also doesn't have option for timefilter. mean, if admin need to check the particular time interval report, he has to come back to search panel. But unable to do the same in dashboard panel. Is there any option to enable time filter option in dashboard panel itself ?